# @Binding is being published twice on @StateObject vs View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

### Overview

- I have a `@StateObject` that is being used to drive a `NavigationSplitView`.
- I am using the `@Published` properties on the `@StateObject` to drive the selection of the view. `@StateObject + @Published`
- When I get to the final selection of the `NavigationSplitView` I want to create a `Selection`.
- This should publish a property **only once**.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Consumption: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Frequency: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Selection: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var consumption: Consumption
    var frequency: Frequency
}


class SomeModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let consump: [Consumption] = ["Coffee","Tea","Beer"].map { str in Consumption(name: str)}
    let freq: [Frequency] = ["daily","weekly","monthly"].map { str in Frequency(name: str)}

    @Published var consumption: Consumption?
    @Published var frequency: Frequency?
    @Published var selection: Selection?
    
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(consumption: Consumption? = nil, frequency: Frequency? = nil, selection: Selection? = nil) {
        self.consumption = consumption
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.selection = selection
        
        $frequency
            .print()
            .sink { newValue in
                if let newValue = newValue {
                    print("THIS SHOULD APPEAR ONCE")
                    print("---------------")
                    self.selection = .init(consumption: self.consumption!, frequency: newValue)
                } else {
                    print("NOTHING")
                    print("---------------")
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellable)
    }
    
}
```

### Problem

The `@StateObject` on the view is publishing the **property twice**. (See code below)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: SomeModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            VStack {
                List(model.consump, selection: $model.consumption) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Label(item.name, systemImage: "circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
        } content: {
            switch model.consumption {
            case .none:
                Text("nothing")
            case .some(let consumption):
                List(model.freq, id:\.id, selection: $model.frequency) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item.name, value: item)
                }
                .navigationTitle(consumption.name)
            }
        } detail: {
            switch model.selection {
            case .none:
                Text("nothing selected")
            case .some(let selection):
                VStack {
                    Text(selection.consumption.name)
                    Text(selection.frequency.name)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: example of twice published]

### My Solution

If I change the View by creating `@State` properties on the view and then use `OnChange` modifier to update the model I get the property to **update once**. Which is what I want. (see code below)

```swift
 struct ContentView: View {
     
     @StateObject var model: SomeModel = .init()
     
     @State private var consumption: Consumption?
     @State private var frequency: Frequency?

     var body: some View {
         NavigationSplitView {
             VStack {
                 List(model.consump, selection: $consumption) { item in
                     NavigationLink(value: item) {
                         Label(item.name, systemImage: "circle.fill")
                     }
                 }
             }.onChange(of: consumption) { newValue in
                 self.model.consumption = newValue
             }
         } content: {
             switch model.consumption {
             case .none:
                 Text("nothing")
             case .some(let consumption):
                 List(model.freq, id:\.id, selection: $frequency) { item in
                     NavigationLink(item.name, value: item)
                 }
                 .navigationTitle(consumption.name)
                 .onChange(of: frequency) { newValue in
                     self.model.frequency = newValue
                 }
             }
         } detail: {
             switch model.selection {
             case .none:
                 Text("nothing selected")
             case .some(let selection):
                 VStack {
                     Text(selection.consumption.name)
                     Text(selection.frequency.name)
                 }
             }
         }

     }
 }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

### Question(s) / Help

Is the behaviour of `@Binding` different between `@StateObject + @Published` vs `View + @State`?

I don't understand why in my previous View the property was being published twice.

My solution is a bit more work but it works by using `@State` and `onChange` view modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can´t completely explain why this happens. It seems that `List` updates its selection twice.

Why? Unknown. *?May be a bug?*.

Consider this debugging approach:

```
} content: {
        switch model.consumption {
        case .none:
            Text("nothing")
        case .some(let consumption):
            // Create a custom binding and connect it to the viewmodel
            let binding = Binding<Frequency?> {
                model.frequency
            } set: { frequency, transaction in
                model.frequency = frequency
                // this will print after the List selected a new Value
                print("List set frequency")
            }
                                      // use the custom binding here
            List(model.freq, id:\.id, selection: binding) { item in
                NavigationLink(item.name, value: item)
            }
            .navigationTitle(consumption.name)
        }
```

This will produce the following output:

```
receive subscription: (PublishedSubject)
request unlimited
receive value: (nil)
NOTHING
---------------
receive value: (Optional(__lldb_expr_7.Frequency(id: D9552E6A-71FE-407A-90F5-87C39FE24193, name: "daily")))
THIS SHOULD APPEAR ONCE
---------------
List set frequency
receive value: (Optional(__lldb_expr_7.Frequency(id: D9552E6A-71FE-407A-90F5-87C39FE24193, name: "daily")))
THIS SHOULD APPEAR ONCE
---------------
List set frequency
```

The reason you are not seeing this while using `@State` and `.onChange` is the `.onChange` modifier. It fires only if the value changes which it does not. On the other hand your `Combine` publisher fires every time no matter the value changed or not.

Solution:

You can keep your Combine approach and use the `.removeDuplicates` modifier.

```
$frequency
    .removeDuplicates()
    .print()
    .sink { newValue in
```

This will ensure the sink will only get called when new values are sent.

Comment: Thank you for that debugging technique. I tried going back to the Combine original and using `.removeDuplicates()` and I have it working but it still bothers me that I have to resort to that. 

In your debugging approach what does `transaction` in `...set: {frequency, transaction}...` do?

Comment: Sorry, don´t know. Never used it. I use this way of constructing a Binding only for debugging purposes [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/transaction).